# Unallocated space on dynamic disc

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. Later, I wanted to uninstall Ubuntu again and got as far as unallocating the space. Then, (yes, I never should have done the whole thing in the first place, I know :( ) I tried to install Ubuntu again but failed. Now I have 9 gb of unallocated space and a 83 gb primary partition that I can't wipe anymore, when I go to the windows partition view and right-click, it only shows "Help" and none of the other options. I'd rather not reinstall windows, is there any way to wipe the primary partition and add it and the unallocated space to the original volume?

Answer (score -1):

If your operating system does not handle this partition type,
use a partition editor that has a boot CD or boot USB that you can boot from
to effect that partition delete.

For a list of partition editor with reviews see
[Best Free Partition Management Software](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-partition-management-software.htm).

Comment: Would the learned downvoter please justify himself. If done by the poster: It's not very nice to penalize people that are only trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you can try a third-party tool to [wipe data](http://www.disk-partition.com/help/wipe-data.html)(such as AOMEI Partition Assistant) on the 83 GB primary partition, then delete it to execute whatever you want. In some cases, A third-party tool can help you solve problems Windows cannot. AOMEI Partition Assistant help me to extend partition a few month ago when the extend volume is greyed out in disk management. 
hope you are a lucky guy